# std::bind and std::function with polymorphism, base class

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to bind an object to a function, but the base's class function is being called.
The code it's just an example for the real code.
I will only have the string later in the real code.

```
 class A {
    public:
        virtual void f(const std::string &s) {
            std::cout << "A " << s << std::endl;
        }
    };

    class B : public A {
    public:
        void f(const std::string &s) override {
            std::cout << "B " << s << std::endl;
        }
    };

    void main() {
        std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();

        std::function<void(const std::string &)> callback
                =  std::bind(&A::f, *a, std::placeholders::_1);
        callback("my string");
    }
```

The result is

```
 A my string
```

I tried to change it to &B:f, but got an error.

```
No viable conversion from 'typename _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<void (B::*)(const basic_string<char> &)>::value, void (B::*)(const basic_string<char> &), A &, const _Placeholder<1> &>::type' (aka '_Bind<void (Centerity::Cluster::Correlation::B::*(Centerity::Cluster::Correlation::A, std::_Placeholder<1>))(const std::basic_string<char> &)>') to 'std::function<void (const std::string &)>' (aka 'function<void (const basic_string<char> &)>')
```

I tried to change it to `A* a = B();` same result.
Couldn't find a similar code anywhere.
Of course creating `B b` will call `B::f`, but that's not helping me.

I can lose the bind and use lambda, but I don't know how.

Comment: main is not void!

Comment: Note that this is undefined behavior if `A::~A` is not `virtual`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE:**

I don't know which compiler you are using but [main](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) shouldn't be void. I have fixed it in my code below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    virtual void f(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cout << "A " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void f(const std::string &s) override 
    {
        std::cout << "B " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();
    auto callback = std::bind(&A::f, a.get(), std::placeholders::_1);

    callback("my string");
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
B my string
```

The catch is to pass pointer to the base class (pointing to an object of derived class) to `std::bind(&A::f, a.get(), std::placeholders::_1);`.

If you pass by value, then a new object of your base class A will be created (by copy constructor) and the f version of base class will be called as you have observed in your program.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer then!

Comment: I can only accept one then sorry I'll choose this one.

Comment: Yes you can choose one accepted answer but you can upvote has one.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for the *lambda* version:

```
class A { 
    public:
        virtual void f(const std::string &s) {
            std::cout << "A " << s << std::endl;
        }   
};  

class B : public A { 
    public:
        void f(const std::string &s) override {
            std::cout << "B " << s << std::endl;
        }
};  

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();

    auto callback = [&a](const std::string& s){ return a->f(s); };

    callback("my string");
}
```